# If a parameter to a stored procedure is null, is there any way to optimize away the dependent joins?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a stored procedure with 20 parameters that searches a highly normalized database, so it needs lots of joins.

In any given search, most of the parameters are null.

If a parameter is null, is there any way to suppress the joins that are now unnecessary to return a result?

Comment: Do you use parameters in your joins? Can you show a sample query?

Comment: You may want to read [this](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/) and [this](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html).

Comment: Sure, let me post some code.

Comment: Have you verified from the query plan that it is joining unnecessarily? Are these joins required to filter the data or do you need to return columns  from the joined tables? If you don't need columns from these tables start by using `EXISTS` to perform the filtering

Comment: @Contango Hi, did you think of using `INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.Column1 = COALESCE(@nullparameter, t2.column1)`?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're using a join to another table for a filter, not to return any columns. You should be using "exists" instead, even outside the original context of this question, to prevent record expansion, which I am guessing you're solving by using "distinct", and for better performance. Then to answer your direct question, the best solution is to make this dynamic sql, and then only add a particular "exists" block if that parameter is not null.